# TypeScript class definitions

Tags: typescript

I'm pretty sure that I can make "class templates" using TypeScript language, but I'm pretty sure I don't know how to declare methods that I don't know, what they have inside of them, but I'm sure that they're existing in the extended classes. And I have got this bunch of code:

```
class Tool {
  protected drawing: boolean;
  readonly assignedName: string;

  constructor(readonly name: string) {
    this.drawing = false;
    this.assignedName = name;
  }

  public getToolName(): string {
    return this.assignedName;
  }

  onMouseMove(
    xC: number,
    yC: number,
    canvasContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D
  ): void;
  onMouseUp(canvasContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D): void;
  onMouseDown(): void;
}

export default Tool;
```

And everything seems to be fine, Visual Studio Code is recognizing that the methods `onMouseMove`, `onMouseUp` and `onMouseDown` exists and have provided properties, but in the `Tool` class I've got TypeScript errors:

```
Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.
```

Can someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for [abstract classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes).

For your specific example, this should work:

```js
abstract class Tool {
  protected drawing: boolean;
  readonly assignedName: string;

  constructor(readonly name: string) {
    this.drawing = false;
    this.assignedName = name;
  }

  public getToolName(): string {
    return this.assignedName;
  }

  abstract onMouseMove(
    xC: number,
    yC: number,
    canvasContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D
  ): void;
  abstract onMouseUp(canvasContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D): void;
  abstract onMouseDown(): void;
}

export default Tool;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've meant, I just forgot the `abstract` name :D. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking to make an abstract class.

See the documentation here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes